# Creating relationships in entity with out foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using the code first approach, to create the database based on modals and the db context class. The problem is that when I create the relationships between one model and the next and run the code the data base generates foreign keys like it should.

How ever I want the relationships, **with out** the foreign keys. is this possible to do with entity framework and the code first approach?

for example:

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string city { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string province { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LocationAssignment> LocationAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Has a relationship with:

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class LocationAssignment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int locationID { get; set; }
        public int serviceID { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public int personID { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public virtual Product product { get; set; }
        public virtual Person person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see this table will have a foreign key generated with the location table. How do I keep this relationship **WITH OUT** the generation of foreign keys?

Comment: Why don't you want foreign keys?

Comment: because apparently the company doesn't understand how to manage a database and will just drop all foreign key constraints after the product is handed off, which will break, or can break the application. So I am experimenting with creating tables using code first approach that doesn't generate foreign keys. Yet keeps the relationships

Comment: that's the weirdest use of code first I heard :) but interesting - so you actually don't want 'FK-s' in the database generated right? (not just 'showing' as a property in your POCO).

Comment: exactly, I could create this as normal and just drop all Foreign keys, but apparently the client would appreciate if it was created with out foreign keys yet keep the relationship. @NSGaga

Answer (score 0):

User Triggers On Insert and on update and delete relative and reference tables !!! but that's not cute you must control allthing in your application instead

Comment: is there not a way, when  you create the database init class to populate the table with dummy data, to say drop foreign key con straights using the db context class?